# TextArea which adapts Line with Linebreak after x characters

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In our **ExtJs5.1.2** project we want to have a **textarea** which breaks the line with a **linefeed after x characters entered**.

e.g. line should max be 5 characters long when entering 12345 the stay on one line and when entering 6 a new line with 6 is in the textarea.

```
12345
6
```

So when the user continuously enters text, the text is autoamtically adapted to a line length of 5.

```
12345
67890
12345
6...
```

I tried it with the following extend of the textarea, but it does not work as expected.
The function `adaptLines` formats the value accordingly to a line length of 5, but it is not populated to the textarea itself.

```
Ext.define('LineAdaptTextField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',

    _removeNewLineRegEx: /\n/g,
    _lineAdaptRegEx: /(.{1,5})/g,

    // called when text is entered, but no effect of value in the textfield
    processRawValue: function(value) {
        value = this.callParent([value]);
        var processed = this.adaptLines(value);

        console.info('processRawValue("%s") to "%s"', value, processed);

        return processed;
    },

    // never be called when entering text
    transformRawValue: function(value) {
        value = this.callParent([value]);
        var transformed = this.adaptLines(value);

        console.info('transformRawValue("%s") to "%s"', value, transformed);

        return transformed;
    },

    // is called but no effect on the textfield
    valueToRaw: function (value) {
        value = this.callParent([value]);
        var rawValue = this.adaptLines(value);

        console.info('valueToRaw("%s") to "%s"', value, rawValue);

        return rawValue;
    },

    // never be called when entering text
    rawToValue: function (rawValue) {
        rawValue = this.callParent([rawValue]);
        var value = this.adaptLines(rawValue);

        console.info('valueToRaw("%s") to "%s"', rawValue, value);

        return value;
    },

    // add linefeed after 5 characters
    adaptLines: function(value){
        var noNewLines = value.replace(this._removeNewLineRegEx, '');
        return noNewLines.replace(this._lineAdaptRegEx, '$1\n').replace(/\n$/, '');
    }
});
```

For trying out the problem see this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1af8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution to this issue will be to explicitly setting the formatted value. For example([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ahn)), one can make use of change event:

```
listeners:{
    change: function ( field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
        field.setValue(newValue);
    }
}
```

The value which is returned by `rawToValue` method, is available in `newValue` parameter of `change` event. Calling the `setValue` method by passing the `newValue`as argument will update the texteditor view.

Comment: I tried it and it works as you expressed, but the change event is only fired when the text entering is finished. So the user see when he holds a key that it is formated afterwards. Is there an other posibility to execute the formatting before the text is visible in the textarea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that is possible(not in my little knowledge). Because if user holds a key then during that time even the  "rawToValue" function is not call. According to my understanding we can process input only after user has entered it, not during the key holding time.